# wscanf() behaving differently than scanf() when taking input

Tags: c, string, scanf, c-strings, widestring

I have a simple program which takes user input as a string and output the entered string. The only difference is that I have provided two option to the user,

**First** to input a **basic string**.

**Second** to input a **wide string**.

The **scanf()** successfully takes user input for basic string but **wscanf()** does not prompt for user input and just exit.

Why this is happening with wscanf() and not with scanf() ? How would I take take user input  string from wscanf() in the same program.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void basic()
{
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter string with basic string char: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Entered string : %s \n", str);
}

void wide()
{
    wchar_t str[100];
    wprintf(L"Enter string with wide string char: ");
    wscanf(L"%ls", str);
    wprintf(L"Entered string : %ls \n", str);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int option = 1;
    printf("\n Basic string (char*) vs Wide string (wchar_t*) \n\n");
    printf("1. Basic string \n2. Wide string \n");
    printf("Enter choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        basic();
        break;
    case 2 :
        wide();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

**1. Basic string :**

```
Basic string (char*) vs Wide string (wchar_t*) 

1. Basic string 

2. Wide string 

Enter choice : 1

Enter string with basic string char: hello

Entered string : hello
```

**2. Wide string :**

```
Basic string (char*) vs Wide string (wchar_t*) 

1. Basic string 

2. Wide string 

Enter choice : 2
```

Comment: Check the return value of wscanf. Also it would be good to give details of your compiler and system, as there has been (and still is) a lot of variety in wide string function implementations, often the standard is not followed

Answer (score 1):

> [wscanf() behaving differently than scanf() when taking input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474894/wscanf-behaving-differently-than-scanf-when-taking-input)

Orientation.

Code's first use of `stdin` is `scanf("%d", &option)` establishing a *byte-oriented stream*.

Following use of `wscanf(L"%ls", str);` is UB.  Stick with one orientation or re-open files.

> Each stream has an orientation. After a stream is associated with an external file, but
>   before any operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation. Once a wide
>   character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the
>   stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has
>   been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream.
>   Only a call to the freopen function or the fwide function can otherwise alter the
>   orientation of a stream. (A successful call to freopen removes any orientation.)
>   C11 §7.21.2 4.

Similar issue applies to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

The first `scanf()` command `scanf("%d", &option);` leaves `\n` in `stdin`, which `wscanf()` is catching. That is what causing the error, i think. I had a similar problem a week ago. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237376/store-hex-input-into-int-variable-without-using-scanf-function-in-c), where you can find good answers and workarounds i have get.

You can either put a `getchar()` after `scanf()` to pull out the `\n` or avoid the use of `scanf()` in total and use an alternative, f.e. `sscanf()`.

Comment: But its working for scanf() and not for wscanf(). Secondly, I have put a getchar() prior to wscanf() and it is not taking input.

Comment: `%s` skips leading whitespace so that probably is not an issue